# API 17 - Android notification launches activity without being clicked

Tags: android, notifications

I publish a notification on API 17 and the pending intent is triggered without the notification being clicked.

Here is the code I am using in publishing the notification, what part of the code is triggering this behavior and how can I fix it?

```
 public static void notifyIncomingMessage(Context context, ChatMessage message, String name) throws JSONException {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ChatMessageInterceptor.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, GcmIntentService.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String text = messageText(message, context);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_small_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(name == null ? context.getString(R.string.app_name) : name)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(text))
                        .setContentText(text)
                        .setLargeIcon(getBitmapIcon(context))
                        .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);
        mNotificationManager.notify(GcmIntentService.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: What is triggering the intent? Just reading the notification launches the activity? Or, just receiving the notification is opening the activity again?

Comment: @GuilhermeP the intent triggers when the notification is published

Answer (score 1):

The main cause is due to setFullScreenIntent() method as the document of android tells [developer.android.com][1]
so dont use

```
    mBuilder.setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);
```

and instead just use

```
    mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
```

This will help for showing heads-up notification by default.
Even for setDefaults(), Notification.DEFAULT_ALL is not necessary but good to use.

This is pretty clear and is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it must have been the `fullScreenIntent`. I removed it and added only add it in API >= 19. I still have to test on KitKat devices.

```
if (Utils.hasLollipop())
    mBuilder.setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);
```

Didn't pay attention to the docs but here it is.

> An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status
>   bar. Only for use with extremely high-priority notifications demanding
>   the user's immediate attention, such as an incoming phone call or
>   alarm clock that the user has explicitly set to a particular time. If
>   this facility is used for something else, please give the user an
>   option to turn it off and use a normal notification, as this can be
>   extremely disruptive.
>
> On some platforms, the system UI may choose to display a heads-up
>   notification, instead of launching this intent, while the user is
>   using the device.

I actually only want the heads-up notification but how one detects devices who have it or don't have it is another problem entirely.